# How to make sure there is not multiple instances of imported modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Currently making a RN app and I will integrate this with Google Analytics and Firebase. I will use this module: https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge

I am building a wrapper class/module that will be contacting every provider so I can extend my own in the future easily.

My structure is as follows (each class extends the other):
React Component -> BaseComponent -> (Specific Implementation) -> ScreenComponent

Since a screen can have multiple components and I will put the analytics wrapper in my BaseComponent there will be multiple calls to the analytics module I am building.

I am still a little new into this require/exports coming from Java development so to me there will be multiple instances of this module creating multiple sessions.

I was thinking on making the analytics wrapper a global object, to make sure the setup code is only run once, and the session is being kept.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both nodejs native require and requirejs automatically handles this.

Beware, this is two edged sword - changing properties of imported module also changes them in all other scripts that import them, similarly to changing Java static property.

Comment: Excellent. Just to confirm, so I can think of the modules imported as shared code in all the files that imported them. I was thinking it was like copy/pasting into the file but I understand this is not the case.

Comment: Unless you do something crazy like loading same module using completely different paths, the code is shared and loaded only once. Same applies on es6 `import`s.

Comment: No, same path. Actually it will be loaded once by the BaseComponent. I guess I only need to make sure the session is only created once during the app lifecycle.